# Pass checkbox boolean to parent react componenet

Tags: onchange, react-props, react-functional-component

**Goal**

I want to pass the boolean from an checkbox to an parent element to change a state there.

**Description**

I have the following function (shortened):

```
 export default function Contact() {
      const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState();

...

    function handleCheck() {
        setIsChecked(!isChecked);
      }

...

return (

...

     <CheckBoxContainer>
                    <CheckBox type="checkbox" defaultChecked={isChecked} onChange={handleCheck} />{" "}
                    <CheckBoxText>
                      Ich habe die{" "}
                      <SmallInlineLink to="/privacy">Datenschutzbestimmungen</SmallInlineLink> zur
                      Kenntnis genommen.
                    </CheckBoxText>
                  </CheckBoxContainer>

<Button
              disabled={
                isChecked !== true
              }
            >
              Abschicken
            </Button>

)}
```

That works so far.
But i want to reuse the `CheckBoxContainer` in a couple of forms and for that i want to make it a functional component.

**It should look like this:**

```
export default function Contact() {
          const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState();

    ...

        function handleCheck() {
            setIsChecked(!isChecked);
          }

    ...

    return (

    ...

         <CheckBoxContainer checked={isChecked} onChange={handleCheck} />


    <Button
                  disabled={
                    isChecked !== true
                  }
                >
                  Abschicken
                </Button>

    )}
```

So that i have a reusable `Checkboxcontainer`, like this:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import React from "react";
import { CheckBox } from "../Form/InputFields";
import { CheckBoxText } from "../Text";
import { SmallInlineLink } from "../Navigation/NavLinks";

export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

export default function CheckBoxContainer(isChecked, handleCheck) {
  console.log("Checkbox Component" + isChecked);
  return (
    <Container>
      <CheckBox type="checkbox" defaultChecked={!isChecked} onChange={() => handleCheck} />{" "}
      <CheckBoxText>
        Ich habe die <SmallInlineLink to="/privacy">Datenschutzbestimmungen</SmallInlineLink> zur
        Kenntnis genommen.
      </CheckBoxText>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

**Question**

> How do i pass the boolean from the `CheckBoxContainer` correctly to
>   the parent element?
>
> At the moment the console.log shows me an [object Object]

**Possible Solution**

Function call in the parent element:

```
{CheckBoxContainer(isChecked, () => setIsChecked(!isChecked))}
```

Child Function:

```
export default function CheckBoxContainer(isChecked, setIsChecked) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <CheckBox
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={isChecked}
        onChange={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
      />{" "}
      <CheckBoxText>
        Ich habe die <SmallInlineLink to="/privacy">Datenschutzbestimmungen</SmallInlineLink> zur
        Kenntnis genommen.
      </CheckBoxText>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Thanks @viknek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for this:

1. You can call `CheckBoxContainer` as functional component in jsx:

`{ CheckBoxContainer(isChecked, () => setIsChecked(!isChecked)) }`.

This way `CheckBoxContainer` is treated as a function and therefore the two arguments in `CheckBoxContainer` are treated as corresponding arguments that you pass to the function, in this case `isChecked` and the `callback`.

2. When you call `<CheckBoxContainer />` and pass props they are accessible inside `CheckBoxContainer` this way: `props.isChecked` and `props.handleCheck`. So you can either use deconstructing:

`const CheckBoxContainer = ({ isChecked, handleCheck} ) => ...`

or access props with dot notation

`const CheckBoxContainer = (props) => (<div onClick={props.handleCheck}>{props.isChecked}</div>)`